# ERROR: sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0777, should be 0440

Tags: sudo

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0777, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers source found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I have Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 LTS and this sudo problem, i cant use sudo command, please help everyone, how to fix this sudo error.

[image]

Please Help!

Comment: post the output of `ls -l /etc/sudoers`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
chmod -R a+rx /etc/sudoers.d
chmod -R u+w /etc/sudoers.d
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/README
```

As written here: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?54790-SOLVED-sudo-etc-sudoers-is-mode-0777-should-be-0440/page2&s=c30714d17a797062285f772898ca2f2b